# What's the correct way to refer to types of property name and value pair of an object?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an object with properties of different types. Is there a way in TypeScript to have a generic function that performs an operation on a given key and value of an object?

Here's an example. I have an object `s` with three fields of different types:

```
interface Struct {
  a: string
  b: boolean
  c: string
}

const s: Struct = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: false,
  c: 'world',
}
```

Suppose I have a function that does something with one of the properties:

```
function makeSetter<K, V>(name: K): (value: V) => void {
  return (value) => s[name] = value;
}
```

How should I parametrize types `K` and `V` so that for `makeSetter('a')` I would get a function of type `(value: string) => void` and for `makeSetter('b')` I would receive a function of type `(value: boolean) => void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use generic constraints. `K` must be a `keyof Struct` and `V` must be assignable to `Struct[K]`. [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)

```
interface Struct {
  a: string
  b: boolean
  c: string
}

const s: Struct = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: false,
  c: 'world',
}

function makeSetter<K extends keyof Struct, V extends Struct[K]>(name: K): (value: V) => void {
  return (value) => s[name] = value;
}

// Helpers for type "unit tests"
type Equal<T, U> = [T] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T] ? true : false : false
function assertTrue<T extends true>() {}

const a = makeSetter('a')
const b = makeSetter('b')

assertTrue<Equal<typeof a, (value: string) => void>>() // No error
assertTrue<Equal<typeof b, (value: boolean) => void>>() // No error
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach by `Gerrit0` is useful. Here is a second useful approach ([that is also in the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpigVwWZBvAKGWTgC5kBnDUAcwG4jkAjcpgezYBsI4QHiE5KlFoMAvgQII2IKpXLosOZAF58jMsgBEACwidObLQBpGLZPE4UIpgeS0B3NlE4ATLQTEMCMTCBzAMsgAtnAA1hCoEGCQUAA8ANLIEAAekCCuFMgRAJ5sMGgY2GAAfAAUIHDBEOQJAJTkZQBucJyYNYVKYADaCQC6daolyE1swK7qxFDRmFAgI63tQ8hlFN2V1X2qC20QdeKS0rK41jHQAIzboRFRZ1BlWnBadQ8wHM8MR3KnsQBMV+FItFYg8mM9Xu99sgAPTQ5JQKDOKQyb7A6AAZgBNzR9y0CHBlms+wIQA)).

```
function makeSetter<K extends keyof Struct>(name: K): (value: Struct[K]) => void {
  return value => (s[name] = value);
}

const setter1 = makeSetter("a")("foo");
const setter2 = makeSetter("b")("foo"); // error
const setter3 = makeSetter("c")(false);
```

`keyof T` is the **index type query operator** and `T[K]` is the **indexed access operator**. Both are described under the heading [Index Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) in the Advanced Types docs.